# Spring Batch Execution Status Backed by Database

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jdbc

From the [Spring Guides](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/):

> For starters, the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation adds many critical
>   beans that support jobs and saves you a lot of leg work. This example
>   uses a memory-based database (provided by @EnableBatchProcessing),
>   meaning that when it’s done, the data is gone.

How can I make the execution state backed by a database (or some other *persistent* record) so that, in case the application crashes, the job is resumed from the previous state?

My solution, until now, is having my `ItemReader` be an `JdbcCursorItemReader` which reads records from a table *whose column `X` is not `NULL`*, and my `ItemWriter` be a `JdbcBatchItemWriter` which *updates the record with data on column `X`*, making it non-null (so that it won't be picked on the next execution). However, this seems really hackish and I believe there's a more elegant way. Can anyone please shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation, if you provide a `DataSource` bean definition called `dataSoure`, Spring Batch will use that database for the job repository store instead of the in memory map.  You can read more about this functionality in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html